# How to explain to get JSON and the return to LISTVIEW in android development

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, listview

**I'm self-taught , several knowledge combined together when there is an error , how I should be modified to allow this program up and running**

here warning

```
List<Map<String, Object>> index_shop_data = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>(); // (DeBug)here has a error ,why?
```

Thank you to answer

> MainActivity.java

```
package com.g.gndroid;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

@SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int MSG_SUCCESS = 0;
    private static final int MSG_FAILURE = 1;
    private ListView index_shop_list;
    private TextView tv;
    private Button mButton;

    private Thread mThread;

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
            case MSG_SUCCESS:
                tv.setText((String) msg.obj);
                List<Map<String, Object>> index_shop_data = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>(); // (DeBug)here has a error ,why?
                for (int i = 0; i < ((JSONArray) msg.obj).length(); i++) {
                    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                    map.put("position", "int_position" + i);
                    map.put("name", "int_name" + i);
                    index_shop_data.add(map);
                }
                index_shop_list.setAdapter(new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this,
                        index_shop_data, R.layout.shop_item_list, new String[] {
                                "position", "name" }, new int[] {
                                R.id.tv_position, R.id.tv_name }));
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(),
                        getApplication().getString(R.string.get_pic_success),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;

            case MSG_FAILURE:
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(),
                        getApplication().getString(R.string.get_pic_failure),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.hello_world);

        index_shop_list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.itemList);

        mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mThread == null) {
                    mThread = new Thread(runnable);
                    mThread.start();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText('String',Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    Toast.makeText(
                            getApplication(),
                            getApplication().getString(R.string.thread_started),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet hg = new HttpGet("http://192.168.1.213/1.php");// url
            String strResult = "", status = "", nl = "\n", finalResult = "";
            boolean JSON = false;
            JSONArray DataJSON = null;

            try {
                HttpResponse hr = hc.execute(hg);
                strResult = EntityUtils.toString(hr.getEntity());
                JSONObject strJSON = new JSONObject(strResult);
                String Code = strJSON.getString("Code");
                String Message = strJSON.getString("Message");
                if (Integer.parseInt(Code) == 1) {
                    finalResult = "status:" + Message + nl;
                    DataJSON = strJSON.getJSONArray("Datas");
                    for (int i = 0; i < DataJSON.length(); i++) {
                        status = status
                                + DataJSON.getJSONObject(i).getString("I") + nl
                                + DataJSON.getJSONObject(i).getString("R") + nl
                                + DataJSON.getJSONObject(i).getString("P") + nl
                                + DataJSON.getJSONObject(i).getString("N") + nl;
                    }
                    finalResult = finalResult + status;
                    JSON = true;
                } else {
                    finalResult = Message;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                mHandler.obtainMessage(MSG_FAILURE).sendToTarget();
                return;
            }
            if (!JSON)
                mHandler.obtainMessage(MSG_SUCCESS, finalResult).sendToTarget();
            else
                mHandler.obtainMessage(MSG_SUCCESS, DataJSON).sendToTarget();
        }
    };

}
```

> hello_world.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TextView>
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app_name" >
    </Button>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" >
    </ImageView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/itemList"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

> shop_item_list.xml (ListView)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_position"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dip"
        android:paddingTop="5dip"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dip"
        android:paddingTop="5dip"
        android:text="@string/app_name_text"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you to answer

Comment: I don't even understand what your Q is. You're new, so welcome to StackOverflow and please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Your question wasnt so clear to me, but i tried to run the code. I had few errors but not where you pointed. i got the error at `Toast.makeText('String',Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()`, it should be `Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "String", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();` (you have to pass the context, and put a semicolon after the statement). Now the program is working. i can see an activity with a button, clicking which showed the toast.